# AWS EC2 linux 2 ami postfix mailserver error connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, postfix-mta

i've configured a mail server on my was ec2 which is linux 2 ami. But unfortunately whenever I try to send a mail from my server to a gmail account or yahoo account the maillog show me that connection timed out. I've created the following steps

1. created a subdomain named mail.domain.com pointed to my AWS Elastic Load Balancer on route 53
2. installed postfix
3. added my_domain = domain.com and hostname = mail.domain.com inet_protocol = ipv4
4. created my hostname as mail.domain.com
5. I have checked the ports 25 is running and it is also allowed on my aws security groups.
6. mail status on log is **deferred**

Now I really need to setup the mail server but I am not being able to create it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: AWS has a mail sending service called SES.

Comment: As a general statement you're going to have a difficult time sending email from your server.  It will take months or more to have the Google and Yahoo's of the world to trust your server.  As mentioned, I'd integrate with [SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) to make it so your mail can be delivered.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. 
but my team is not going to use any paid service. Thats why I need to implement this without the ses. 
Could you please help me with that?

Comment: SES is free for the first 62000 messages a month.  How many are you going to send?

Comment: Well, we are developing everything custom and our initial target is to reach to at least 1000 customers a day and also we want to make the mailing service to last long. That's why we were thinking to build our custom mail server.

Comment: You should check your *outbound* security group configuration.  Google uses port 465 and 587 for mail.  I don't know if they even still support 25.  Those are standard ports for SSL and TLS respectively.  But, again, Google very well may reject your connection request as your IP is not in their pass list.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove SMTP throttling. You can learn more about it below.

> AWS blocks outbound traffic on port 25 (SMTP) of all EC2 instances and Lambda functions by default. If you want to send outbound traffic on port 25, you can request for this restriction to be removed.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/